# How can I run OpenOMR?

Tags: java, windows

Hi I'm very new to Java but want to use a program called OpenOMR which reads sheet music and converts it to MIDI files. I want to open the program, but all I see is bits and pieces of Java and class files. There is a README file where it says use the following command.

Windows:

```
java -classpath PATH_TO_JOONE\joone-engine.jar:PATH_TO_JCOMMON\jcommon-1.0.5.jar:.:PATH_TO_JFREECHART\jfreechart-1.0.1.jar  -Xmx256m openomr.openomr.SheetMusic
```

I typed in the paths and copy pasted the line to cmd, but all it returned was this:

```
??: ?? ??? openomr.openomr.SheetMusic?<?> ??? ??? ? ????.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: https://github.com/busterlj/Part-II-Project there is audiveris-3\audiveris.bat which works without problems in Windows, but need good resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first prerequisite is the open source [joone](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joone/). I moved the jar file to the same folder where I extracted `OpenOMR`

```
~/src/OpenOMR $ mv ~/Downloads/joone-engine-20050130.jar .
```

the second is [JFreeChart](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/)

```
~/src/OpenOMR $ unzip ~/Downloads/jfreechart-1.0.19.zip
```

I then successfully ran it with

```
~/src/OpenOMR $ export FREECHART="jfreechart-1.0.19/lib"
~/src/OpenOMR $ export CLASSPATH="$FREECHART/jcommon-1.0.23.jar"
~/src/OpenOMR $ export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$FREECHART/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar"
~/src/OpenOMR $ export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:joone-engine-20050130.jar:."
~/src/OpenOMR $ java openomr.openomr.SheetMusic
```

Finally,

```
~/src/OpenOMR $ echo $CLASSPATH
jfreechart-1.0.19/lib/jcommon-1.0.23.jar:jfreechart-1.0.19/lib/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar:joone-engine-20050130.jar:.
```

I did it on Linux with bash. For Windows, assuming you extracted `OpenOMR` to `C:\` and copied `joone-engine-20050130.jar` to `c:\OpenOMR` and extracted `jfreechart-1.0.19.zip` to `c:\jfreechart-1.0.19` that might look something like

```
cd\OepnOMR
set "FREECHART=c:\jfreechart-1.0.19"
set "CLASSPATH=%FREECHART%\jcommon-1.0.23.jar"
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%FREECHART%\jfreechart-1.0.19.jar"
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;joone-engine-20050130.jar;."
java openomr.openomr.SheetMusic
```

Comment: Do i run the following code in cmd?  when I run the first line, it returns '~'is not recognized as an internal or external comand, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @user2874264 I added a Windows example.

Comment: Here is a error in  windows:

l o g 4 c ... 

but the software can run.

Comment: old post, but when I try to run it, windows cmd throws `Error: Could not find or load main class openomr.openomr.SheetMusic`... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1) [Download Part II Project](https://github.com/busterlj/Part-II-Project) - ZIP is enough (47.5MB).

2) Part-II-Project-master\audiveris-3\audiveris.bat

3) Create a batch in Part-II-Project-master\OpenOMR\ and run OpenORM (did not found save feature, but during play notes are printed in cmd window.

```
set FREECHART=..\jfreechart-1.0.13
set CLASSPATH=..\jfreechart-1.0.13\lib\jcommon-1.0.16.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;..\jfreechart-1.0.13\lib\jfreechart-1.0.13.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;..\joone-engine-2.0.0RC1\joone-engine.jar;.

setlocal
java -Xmx256M openomr.openomr.SheetMusic
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: Found it https://www.reddit.com/comments/26z0m6 and have a lot of JDK / JRE installed during playing with original OpenORM (for example jdk-8u201-windows-i586.exe, OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_8u242b08.msi).

Comment: Or direct link https://github.com/Audiveris/audiveris/releases